# ora-09925 unable to create audit trail file no such file or directory

Tags: oracle, database-administration, oracle12c

I have just installed a oracle 12c 12.1.0 DB on a linux machine.

after completing the installation i tried to login to database as sysdba

```
[oracle@bjorn adump]$ sqlplus sys as sysdba/welcome

SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Wed Oct 12 16:41:17 2016

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter password:
Connected to an idle instance.
```

Now i tried to startup the DB using below command

```
SQL> startup mount
ORA-09925: Unable to create audit trail file
Linux-x86_64 Error: 2: No such file or directory
Additional information: 9925
```

and this error pop up !

my ENV variable are --

```
[oracle@bjorn adump]$ echo $ORACLE_BASE
/oracle
[oracle@bjorn adump]$ echo $ORACLE_HOME
/oracle/product/12.1.0/db_1
```

I have checked into pfile which is $ORACLE_HOME/dbs/init.ora

there is the entry for audit file

```
audit_file_dest="/oracle/admin/orcl/adump"
```

I also go to this location and check if the folder exists or nt but the folder was there and it aleady has some files in it like

```
orcl_m000_21634_20161012143245012051143795.aud
```

there are lots of file with names like this.

I gave permission to this folder

```
chmod -R 755 /oracle/admin/orcl/adump
```

tried creating a new file using

```
touch afile
```

and file get created.

It also got connect to the idle session but when i tried to do a startup the error pops up !

Please suggest what i am overlooking here which needs to be corrected.

Comment: Make sure you have set $ORACLE_SID and $ORACLE_UNQNAME. Then check your listener is configured correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Usually this could happen because:

1. AUDIT_FILE_DEST is not writable(chown +w $AUDIT_FILE_DEST)
2. $ORACLE_BASE/admin/$ORACLE_SID/adump exists and is not writable
3. $ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/audit is not writable

PS: Make sure to check permissions for the oracle user

Also please check for disk space availability

Comment: I have checked the permission and they all the permission as i mentioned that even i can create file using touch command 
Space is available 
[oracle@bjorn adump]$ df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_bjorn-lv_root
                       35G   20G   14G  58% /
tmpfs                 1.5G     0  1.5G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1             477M   73M  379M  17% /boot
shmfs                 1.5G     0  1.5G   0% /dev/shm

Comment: Please check if the param is the same in the spfile: `show parameter audit_file_dest`, check if the location contains some existing audit files, if it does, try to remove them.

Comment: The directory `$ORACLE_BASE/admin/$ORACLE_SID/adump` was removed. After manually creating it everything works!

Answer (score 0):

In our case, one of the drives in one of our 2-node RAC servers was failing - the reason why the OS (Linux) limited anyone's access, including root, to read-only.

The amber light was suppose to turn on but it didn't. It only turned on when we restarted that particular node.

Answer (score -1):

You also have 3 things to verify:
- As already mentionned, check free space with df -have
- Check if the file system are Read/Write or read-only: cat /proc/mounts
- Finally, you can check free inodes space with df -i

Detailled information can be found here: https://www.oracle-scripts.net/unable-to-create-audit-trail-file-read-only-file-system/